# Difference between i686-pc-linux-gnu- and i686-pc-cygwin-

Tags: c, linux, cygwin

I am trying to compile Linux on cygwin, got tool chain which contains i686-pc-linux-gnu-* and
     i686-pc-cygwin-*, i thought i686-pc-linux-gnu-* is for compiling linux, not sure with 
     i686-pc-cygwin-*. for me i686-pc-cygwin-gcc.exe is working fine, but 
     i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc.exe is not working.
     thanks in advance.

Comment: One compiler (`i686-pc-cygwin-gcc.exe`) is targeting Windows and Cygwin, the other (`i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc.exe`) is targeting Linux. Both are *hosted* on the same platform though (Windows). So the compiler for the Linux target is a [*cross-compiler*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler). While the underlying hardware of both could be the same, the format of the generated executable files are not. Executable files generated for one system can't be used on another system.

Comment: That problem is a completely different question, please create a new question showing what you attempt to do, and include the relevant code and the complete and unedited error output.

Comment: Sure, i exported the bin w.r.t i686-pc-linux-gnu- and trying to compile a c file using i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc.exe it is not compiling / why it is compiling only with i686-pc-cygwin-gcc.exe. Can i assume that i cannot compile any applications with i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc.exe in cygwin ?

Comment: Please *edit your question* to include all that information you just posted in the comment. Then while editing the question, add the code that causes the errors, and the actual errors (complete and unedited). Without that information it's *impossible* to say anything.